# How to add slick silder in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress-theming, slick.js

I am trying to use slick slider in my wordpress theme and it does not work at all. the only thing i could see is the two images with two title and two description. could you tell me why the slider is not working at all?

**function.php**

```
 function cardiff_slick_slider() {
        wp_register_style( 'cardiff-slick', get_stylesheet_uri().'/assets/plugins/slick/slick.css',  'all' );
        wp_register_style( 'cardiff-slick-theme', get_stylesheet_uri().'/assets/plugins/slick/slick-theme.css', 'all' );
        wp_register_script( 'cardif-slick-init', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick-init.js', array('slickjs'));
        wp_register_script('cardiff-slick-slider', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'assets/plugins/slick/slick.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'cardiff-slick' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'cardiff-slick-theme' );
        wp_enqueue_script ('cardiff-slick-slider');
        wp_enqueue_script ('cardiff-slick-init');
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cardiff_slick_slider');
```

This is my **index.php** where i got the required data with the help of custom post types.

```
    this is my index.php
    $args=array('post_type'=>'slider');
    $loop=new WP_Query($args);
    if($loop->have_posts()):?>
         <section class="bailboard">
              <div class="main-slider">
                  <?php while($loop->have_posts()):$loop->the_post();?>
                            <div class="slider-item">
                                <div class="slider-content">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="headlines">
                                            <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                                                    <p><?php the_content();?></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                        endwhile;
                  ?>
               </div>
         </section>

        <?php
             else:
        echo'<p>No Content Found</p>';
    endif;
```

Comment: slick slider in your theme.

Comment: yup could you help me with this?

Comment: why are go for code.you can use plugin

Comment: yeah i get it but is it not possible to work with code?

Comment: I just make solution please check answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin for that:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-slick-slider-and-image-carousel/

If you want to integrate into a code then use `do_shortcode()` function.

```
  <?php  echo do_shortcode( '[slick-slider <design code>]' ); ?>
```

For carousel-slider,

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[slick-carousel-slider <design code>]' ); ?>
```

Comment: install plugin create slider.and got to your index.php file and use shortcode.that's it.